# Continue to click the button one after another until you succeed to click a button without any error (Ruby Selenium/Webdriver)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to make a click but only if the element is clickable, but I having a problem because the element clickable is random. The first button can be available on the first, second, third (he was clickable on third line as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXpfU.jpg)), and the fourth and fifth line can appear sometimes, so I need to Ruby try to click on `Cart_ctl00_ctl06_Detail10_ctl04_btnCancelOn`, if can't click pass to `Cart_ctl00_ctl06_Detail10_ctl08_btnCancelOn` and this goes on until the last line

```
...
sleep 5
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 40)
    wait.until do
    browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl06_Detail10_ctl04_btnCancelarOn").click
    el3 = browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl04_GECBtnExpandColumn")
    browser.action.double_click(el3).perform    
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl06_Detail10_ctl08_btnCancelarOn").click
    el5 = browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl04_GECBtnExpandColumn")
    browser.action.double_click(el5).perform
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl06_Detail10_ctl10_btnCancelarOn").click
    el6 = browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl04_GECBtnExpandColumn")
    browser.action.double_click(el6).perform
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl06_Detail10_ctl12_btnCancelarOn").click
    el7 = browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl04_GECBtnExpandColumn")
    browser.action.double_click(el7).perform
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
end
browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl06_Detail10_ctl06_btnCancelarOn").click
el8 = browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl06_GECBtnExpandColumn")
browser.action.double_click(el8).perform        
...
```

HTML from third line:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucCancBloqRem$gridListCartoes$ctl00$ctl06$Detail10$ctl08$btnCancelarOn" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl06_Detail10_ctl08_btnCancelarOn" title="Cancelar Cartão" src="../../../App_Themes/Con/Images/CancelarOn.png" style="border-width:0px;">
```

Error

```
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': unknown error: Element <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucCancBloqRem$gridListCartoes$ctl00$ctl06$Detail10$ctl08$btnCancelarOn" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl06_Detail10_ctl08_btnCancelarOn" title="Cancelar Cartão" src="../../../App_Themes/Con/Images/CancelarOn.png" style="border-width:0px;"> is not clickable at point (563, 150). Other element would receive the click: <div class="raDiv">...</div> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:84:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:84:in `create_response'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:104:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:62:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:166:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/oss/bridge.rb:584:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/oss/bridge.rb:326:in `click_element'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:72:in `click'
    from C:/test/driver_teste3.rb:48:in `rescue in block in <main>'
    from C:/test/driver_teste3.rb:44:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/wait.rb:54:in `until'
    from C:/test/driver_teste3.rb:43:in `<main>'
[Finished in 55.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: ruby "C:\test\driver_teste3.rb"]
[dir: C:\test]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Ruby25-x64\bin]
```

Comment: You want to continue to click the button one after another until you succeed to click a button without any error?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for translate what I'm trying to ask @Rajagopalan hahahahahahaha

Comment: Added HTML for object.

Comment: Thanks @Rajagopalan! Works perfectly! Did you know where I can find guides to learn those things? It's really hard to get more information about Ruby.

Comment: Learn WATIR here http://watir.com/guides/ and for selenium Ruby Binding https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings Remember the people who has Ruby Selenium Binding are the same people has the WATIR Binding, WATIR is the good wrapper around Ruby Selenium binding, there are plenty of other things which you might not know would be taken of by WATIR when you use WATIR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
["04", "08", "10", "12"].each do |num|
  begin
    browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl06_Detail10_ctl#{num}_btnCancelarOn").click
    el3 = browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl04_GECBtnExpandColumn")
    browser.action.double_click(el3).perform
    break
  rescue
  end
end
```

If you use WATIR which is wrapper around Ruby Selenium Binding then,

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
["04", "08", "10", "12"].each do |num|
  begin
    browser.image(id: "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl06_Detail10_ctl#{num}_btnCancelarOn").click
    browser.image(id: "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCancBloqRem_gridListCartoes_ctl00_ctl04_GECBtnExpandColumn").double_click #hope this is image as well 
    break
  rescue
  end
end
```

If you use watir, then waiting while finding an element is automatic, If you don't use watir, then you need to set implicit wait for find_element to wait for a given period of time.